# Run MySQL on Port 3307 Using Docker Compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, prisma

I am trying to create multiple Prisma database services on a single machine. I have been unable to create a MySQL database on a port other than 3306 using Docker Compose.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
hackernews:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.8
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "${CLIENT_PORT}:${INTERNAL_PORT}"
    environment:
    PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: $INTERNAL_PORT
        managementApiSecret: $PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET
        databases:
        default:
            connector: mysql
            host: mysql
            port: $SQL_INTERNAL_PORT
            user: root
            password: $SQL_PASSWORD
            migrations: true
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $SQL_PASSWORD
    volumes:
    - ./custom/:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
    - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
mysql:
```

docker-compose.override.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
mysql:
    expose:
    - "${SQL_INTERNAL_PORT}"
    ports:
    - "${SQL_CLIENT_PORT}:${SQL_INTERNAL_PORT}"
```

Error:

```
hackernews_1  | Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: database - Connection is not available, request timed out after 5008ms.
hackernews_1  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:548)
hackernews_1  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:186)
hackernews_1  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:145)
hackernews_1  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:83)
hackernews_1  |     at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:18)
hackernews_1  |     at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.<init>(JdbcBackend.scala:439)
hackernews_1  |     at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:47)
hackernews_1  |     at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:38)
hackernews_1  |     at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(BasicBackend.scala:218)
hackernews_1  |     at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession$(BasicBackend.scala:217)
hackernews_1  |     at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(JdbcBackend.scala:38)
hackernews_1  |     at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(BasicBackend.scala:239)
hackernews_1  |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
hackernews_1  |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
hackernews_1  |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
hackernews_1  | Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=mysql)(port=3307)(type=master) : Connection refused (Connection refused)
hackernews_1  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:161)
hackernews_1  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.connException(ExceptionMapper.java:79)
hackernews_1  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1040)
hackernews_1  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:490)
hackernews_1  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:144)
hackernews_1  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:90)
hackernews_1  |     at slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.scala:101)
hackernews_1  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:341)
hackernews_1  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:193)
hackernews_1  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:430)
hackernews_1  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$500(HikariPool.java:64)
hackernews_1  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:570)
hackernews_1  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:563)
hackernews_1  |     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                                  PORTS                              NAMES
ab721996469d        mysql:5.7                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   42 minutes ago      Up 55 seconds                           3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3307/tcp   two_mysql_1
7aab98e2b8d7        prismagraphql/prisma:1.8   "/bin/sh -c /app/sta…"   2 hours ago         Restarting (1) Less than a second ago                                      two_hackernews_1
```

.env

```
SQL_PASSWORD=myuniquepassword
SQL_INTERNAL_PORT=3307
SQL_CLIENT_PORT=3307
```

Comment: Could you provide what errors do you have when starts app? and could you provide `docker-compose ps` output?

Comment: Under ports I get "3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3307/tcp"

Comment: And the hackernews Prisma Service is not able to connect to the MySQL database on port 3307. I am going to add the errors above.

Comment: Prisma should use internal `3306` port. And you can expose another (3307) port to host machine. But i cant understand why prisma try to connect to `3307` port. According to config it should connect to `3306`

Comment: also you can remove `    expose:
    - "${SQL_INTERNAL_PORT}"` line. Mysql already exposed this port

Comment: I am telling Prisma to connect to port 3307. I added the .env above.

Comment: Note, another MySQL container is being run on port 3306 and is being used by another Prisma database service.

Comment: it is not a problem. Just name this container `my_second_mysql` and use this name as `hostname`

Comment: But you need to have different EXTERNAL ports for mysql servers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Variable `SQL_INTERNAL_PORT` probably has `3307` value. You need to change it to `3306`.

Also, you can remove

```
    expose:
    - "${SQL_INTERNAL_PORT}"
```

lines. Mysql already exposes 3306 port.

All of the applications into cluster use internal ports (3306 in mysql case). External ports (in section ports) you need only for external word communication.

If you want to have several databases, you need to change docker-compose something like  this:

```
version: '3'
services:
hackernews:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.8
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "${CLIENT_PORT}:${INTERNAL_PORT}"
    environment:
    PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: $INTERNAL_PORT
        managementApiSecret: $PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET
        databases:
        default:
            connector: mysql
            host: mysql_first
            port: 3306
            user: root
            password: $SQL_PASSWORD
            migrations: true
        second:
            connector: mysql
            host: mysql_second
            port: 3306
            user: root
            password: $SQL_PASSWORD
            migrations: true
mysql_first:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $SQL_PASSWORD
    ports:
     - 3307:3306
    volumes:
    - ./custom/:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
    - mysql:/var/lib/mysql

 mysql_second:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
    ports:
     - 3308:3306
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $SQL_PASSWORD
```

Comment: Thank you Bukharov! You are absolutely correct, the machine had ran out of memory and as a result I was assuming that I was doing something wrong (hence why I wanted to run the MySQL database on a different port than 3306).

Answer (score 36):

In my case I could not change the Mysql port rather than 3306 until I add       `MYSQL_TCP_PORT`

So sample:

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3307
    ports:
    - 3307:3307
    expose:
      - 3307
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
      DB_ADDR: mysql
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      DB_PORT: 3307
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: Pa55w0rd
      # Uncomment the line below if you want to specify JDBC parameters. The parameter below is just an example, and it shouldn't be used in production without knowledge. It is highly recommended that you read the MySQL JDBC driver documentation in order to use it.
      #JDBC_PARAMS: "connectTimeout=30000"
    ports:
      - 8040:8080
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammed Ozdogan! I also only could change the port when I add MYSQL_TCP_PORT

Comment: hahahah, the fact that this was the exact problem... XD

Comment: thanks, `MYSQL_TCP_PORT= 3307` env along with `ports: - "3307:3307"`  did it for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I've created this docker-compose.yml and it works perfectly.

Add these instructions for your app container (wordpress for my example) :

```
environment:
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db-wordpress
```

(db-wordpress is the db name container)

Add these instructions for your db container :

```
container_name: db-wordpress
environment:
  VIRTUAL_PORT: 3307
expose:
  - 3307
```

You can create any db container with different port. Just change virtual and expose port. And for your application, the container db name.

I hope, that help someone.