# how to make my mysql docker container accessible on another port apart 3306?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose which contains the following instructions :

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysql-standalone:
    container_name: marqueblanchebd
    image: marqueblanchebd:latest
    ports: 
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
        
  spring-boot:
    image: testmb
    container_name: mbwebservice
    ports:
    - "8091:8080"
    build:
      context: .                          
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
    depends_on:
      - mysql-standalone 
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: ramses2021
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://marqueblanchebd:3307/marque_blanche?useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
    volumes:
      - ./:/uploads/deployment
volumes:
  data:
```

when i run **docker-compose up** the following error occurs from my springboot project:
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

But when i put the default mysql port 3306 ("3306:3306") in docker-compose file, my springboot project connects itself successfully to my database container.
Here is my mysql dockerfile :

```
FROM mysql:latest

EXPOSE 3307
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=marque_blanche
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ramses2021
ADD marque_blanche.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Comment: Do you really want to expose the database to the host operating system?

Comment: Pretty sure the issue is your `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`. Inside of the container `marqueblanchebd` will resolve to the containers IP on the `docker network`, and the connection will be done to port `3307` of the container however the database is listening on port `3306` so you get a connection refused. Basically the traffic does not go from the `spring-boot` service to your host then from your host to the `marqueblanchebd` service rather it goes straight from one service to the other.

Comment: The port mapping works fine provided that the traffic is transiting from the host, run a container on the `host` network connecting to port `3307` e.g.: `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint mysql --network host mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3307`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `docker network` the service name `marqueblanchebd` will resolve to the containers IP. Given the `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://marqueblanchebd:3307/...` the connection attempt is done to the `<container_ip>:3307` however the database is listening on port `3306` hence the connection is refused. For the connection to work you'd need to configure the `mysql` service to listen on port `3307` instead of port `3306`. The traffic does not transit out of the `docker network` to the host then from the host back into the `docker network`.

---

I'd suggest not exposing the database to the host, you can remove the `ports` mappings from the `mysql-standalone` service e.g.:

```yaml
services:
  mysql-standalone:
    container_name: 'marqueblanchebd'
    image: 'marqueblanchebd:latest'
    expose: 
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - 'data:/var/lib/mysql'
```

... and configure the `spring-boot` service to use the default `mysql-standalone` service port:

```yaml
  spring-boot:
    # ...
    environment:
      # ...
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://marqueblanchebd:3306/marque_blanche?useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
      # ...
```

This would isolate the database inside of the `docker network`.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest a simple way to solve the problem :

Just insert this line in docker compose file for mysql service:

```
environment:
  MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3307
```

As it is said in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456780/run-mysql-on-port-3307-using-docker-compose)