FastAPI app in Docker can't connect to MySQL: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db'"
I'm trying to run a FastAPI application with a MySQL database in a Docker environment, but I'm encountering a connection error. The application is unable to connect to the database.
Here's the error I'm getting:
Copysqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

docker-compose.yml:
services:
  backend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
    networks:
      - music-app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=${BACKEND_DATABASE_URL}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: bash -c "alembic upgrade head && uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload"

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - music-app
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
        ]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10

volumes:
  mysql_data:

networks:
  music-app:
    driver: bridge

In my alembic/env.py, I'm trying to connect to the database using mysql+pymysql as the dialect.
I've already tried:
Checking environment variables
Verifying network settings
Setting up a healthcheck for the database
What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?
I've tried the following
Checked environment variables:
Verified that the BACKEND_DATABASE_URL in the .env file is correctly set with the appropriate
format: mysql://[username]:[password]@[host]:[port]/[database_name].
Verified network settings:
Confirmed both backend and db services are on the same music-app network in docker-compose.yml.
Expected: Services to be able to communicate with each other.
Despite these attempts, I'm still unable to establish a connection between the FastAPI backend and the MySQL database. I expected the application to start successfully and be able to communicate with the database.

So what is the URL you're seeing? Since you're running MySQL on a non-standard port, is that actually reflected in the connection string?

MySQL is not running on a non-standard port: port publishing only impacts access from the host; containers on the same network will continue to access MySQL on port 3306.

This question would be easier to answer if you were to provide a [mcve] that we could use to reproduce the problem on our own systems.

Further to port comment from @larsks , what port is your BACKEND_DATABASE_URL using?

Have you seen this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456780/run-mysql-on-port-3307-using-docker-compose

remove one $ from your db health check -p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD for healthcheck to pass which will ease if your db is accessible or not
your:
"mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD", 

new:
"mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",

change your  BACKEND_DATABASE_URL value in .env
from
mysql://root:mysecretpassword@db:3306/mydatabase


to:
mysql+pymysql://root:mysecretpassword@db:3306/mydatabase


because you are using sqlalchemy as seen in the error therefor you will need pymsql as api driver to access mysql

Probably the hostname is wrong. If not set, the hostname will be the container name shown when running docker compose up.
You can control this value by setting mysql hostname in the yaml like:
db:
  hostname: "db"

This usually fixed such errors for me.
